# Google sheets - List of dates between a list of start and end dates

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to list all the dates between a list of start and end dates. I have used sequence formula for each row of dates but I am looking for one single formula to work irrespective of any number of rows I have. Any help is highly appreciated

[image: Indended Result]

Comment: please share a link to your sheet.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17T5t_w5dN89PIXLm7596qnhzX30L289nr7ZzM3Wca2E/edit#gid=1883781078

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I entered this formula in cell E2

```
=sort(query(sequence(max(A2:B)-min(A2:B)+1,1,min(A2:B)),
"where "&join(" or ","(Col1>="&filter(A2:A,A2:A<>"")&" 
and Col1<="&filter(B2:B,B2:B<>"")&")")&
" format Col1 'dd.mmm.yyyy'"))
```

First, we list all the dates from the lowest one to the greatest one in the range A2:B, then we use query to remove all those who aren't between the specified intervals.

Answer (score 3):

While there is already an answer for this, if the same date is repeated in multiple columns, that won't be reflected in the resulting list. Therefore, if you want the dates included in multiple intervals to be repeated, here is an alternative:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(FLATTEN(IF(DAYS(B2:B4,A2:A4)>=SEQUENCE(1,1000,0),A2:A4+SEQUENCE(1,1000,0),"")),"where Col1 is not null"))
```

[image]

- Use `DAYS`, `SEQUENCE` and `IF` to get a list of all the dates in between the intervals.
- Use `FLATTEN` to put all values in a single column.
- Use `QUERY` to remove the null values.

Comment: Didnt work as soon as I change references for entire column. B2:B4 to B2:B.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(FLATTEN(IF(DAYS(B2:B, A2:A)>=SEQUENCE(1, 10000, 0), 
 A2:A+SEQUENCE(1, 10000, 0), )), "where Col1>0 format Col1'dd.mmm.yyyy'"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As an Excel user, I ran across this hoping for an Excel-based answer. I couldn't find one but based on this and other research, I was finally able to figure it out. Put this formula in cell D2:

```
=TOCOL(MAKEARRAY(ROWS(A2:B4), MAX(B2:B4-A2:A4)+1, 
      LAMBDA(row,col, 
          LET(mydate, INDEX(A2:B4,row,1)+col-1, 
              IF(mydate<=INDEX(A2:B4,row,2), mydate, NA()
       )))),2)
```

That's the short version, if a bit confusing. Here's a longer version -- using the LET function to describe some variables to hopefully make it more understandable:

```
=TOCOL( 
     LET(datearray, A2:B4,
         startdatearray, CHOOSECOLS(datearray,1),
         enddatearray, CHOOSECOLS(datearray,2),
         rowcount, ROWS(datearray),
         columncount, MAX(enddatearray-startdatearray)+1,
         MAKEARRAY(rowcount, columncount,
             LAMBDA(row, col,
                 LET(mydate, INDEX(datearray,row,1)+col-1, 
                     IF(mydate<=INDEX(datearray,row,2), mydate, NA()
  ))))),2)
```

Basically, this uses the MAKEARRAY to make a two-dimensional array of all the dates, where each row is a date range (as specified in the original array). The first column of each row is the start date of the range, then it adds one day to each column to the right. If the date in question is larger than the end date for that row, it puts an NA() in that column instead. Finally, it uses the TOCOL function to convert the two-dimensional array to a single column, omitting the NA() values.