# Google Sheets - Expanding dataset according to months between 2 dates

Tags: date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to be able to expand a dataset to include one row per "person" per month, filtered by Start and End Date.

Consider the example below:

[image]

This is the desired outcome

[image]

Inputs are a start and end date, which could be anywhere between the start of a given financial year (01/04/20XX) and the end of that financial year (31/03/20XY).
The output rows contain each month comprised between these 2 dates for which there is a matching entry in the input (see example output)

I have an example sheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1w3M2KEAl6_mc33IIUSErd3BlTzYTHzwx150YLAfQUKs/edit#gid=0).

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: What is the connection between your 1st and 2nd image? Define your inputs clearly please. And link example sheet

Comment: @Argyll I have added a link to a sample sheet. Also updated the first screenshot to include and End date for all. I would like to be able to default to a certain date (end of financial year) when the cell is left blank.

Comment: Your end dates of `31/03` are listed as `2022` where they should both be `2023`, which I'm sure is causing confusion since, as written, your end dates are before your start dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(UNIQUE(QUERY(FLATTEN(IF(DAYS(C2:C4,B2:B4)>=SEQUENCE(1,1000,0),A2:A4&","&TEXT(B2:B4+SEQUENCE(1,1000,0),"YYYY-MMM")&","&D2:D4,"")),"where Col1 is not null")),","))
```

**Result:**
[image]

This works however the only limitation is you have to manually edit the formula to specifically define the End range. It crashes when I set it to use  the whole column using the formula below:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SPLIT(UNIQUE(QUERY(FLATTEN(IF(DAYS(C2:C,B2:B)>=SEQUENCE(1,1000,0),A2:A&","&TEXT(B2:B+SEQUENCE(1,1000,0),"YYYY-MMM")&","&D2:D,"")),"where Col1 is not null")),","))
```

I am assuming this is because of the Query function which runs a Google Visualization API Query Language query across data making it very long and heavy processing.

**Explanation:**

To explain how this works using the formula from this link: [Google sheets - List of dates between a list of start and end dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71391994/google-sheets-list-of-dates-between-a-list-of-start-and-end-dates) to get the dates between, but I changed the `IF` to return all combined 4 columns. Converted it to date format using [TEXT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139?hl=en) (YYYY-MMM). I then used the [UNIQUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198?hl=en) to remove duplicates so it will only show the months. Then make use of [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en) to split across 3 columns.

**References:**

- [Get dates between 2 dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71391994/google-sheets-list-of-dates-between-a-list-of-start-and-end-dates)
- [TEXT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094139?hl=en)
- [UNIQUE](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198?hl=en)
- [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en)
- [SPLIT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094136?hl=en)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Brilliant, thanks a lot for your help! No drama about having to have the range fixed as we're dealing with financial years here, always having 12 months. Thanks

Comment: @user1210226 Glad to know your concern is resolved!